# Loop over word and extract bigram

Tags: unix, awk, sed, text-processing

I would like to extract every single bigram from a given word and put in a text file.

For example:

```
apple      -->       ap pp pl le
president  -->       pr re es si id de en nt
```

I found similar work using awk and word but nothing about words.

I just found this code:

```
sed 's/\(.\{2\}\)/\1 /g'
```

but it's working with a window size of 2.

So, for example:

```
apple      -->      ap pl le
```

Thanks for help

```
sed 's/\(.\{2\}\)/\1 /g'
```

The expected result is a string of bigram with a window size of 1.

Comment: What should it do with single character input like `a`?

Comment: What happen if the word contain special characters? For example app-le? The result should always be: ap pp p- -l le

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this:

```
$ sed 's/./&&/g;s/^.//;s/../& /g;s/ .$//' <<< $'president\napple'
pr re es si id de en nt
ap pp pl le
```

Here is the sed command split up:

```sh
s/./&&/g   # Duplicate every character:   "pprreessiiddeenntt"
s/^.//     # Remove first character:      "prreessiiddeenntt"
s/../& /g  # Insert blank between groups: "pr re es si id de en nt t"
s/ .$//    # Remove last two chars:       "pr re es si id de en nt"
```

Comment: @karakfa `/2g` is implementation specific and works for GNU sed, but not necessarily elsewhere, so I'd rather not use it, but good point on the other command I can crop.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can do this pretty simply:

```
$ cat file.txt
 apple
 president
 example
 another

$ awk '{output=""; for(i=1;i<length($0);i++){ output=output" "substr($0,i,2)} print output }' file.txt
 ap pp pl le
 pr re es si id de en nt
 ex xa am mp pl le
 an no ot th he er
```

If the spaces preceding the lines are a problem you can handle it in numerous ways, such as checking if output is empty before appending a space before the substring, or simply extracting a substring of the output past the space, e.g.

```
$ awk '{output="";for(i=1;i<length($0);i++){ output=output" "substr($0,i,2)} print substr(output,2) }' file.txt
ap pp pl le
pr re es si id de en nt
ex xa am mp pl le
an no ot th he er
```

Everything inside the `{ }` block is executed for each line, as it has no condition attached to it.

`output=""` resets the output variable to empty for each line.

`for(i=1;i<length($0);i++){ ... }` loops through the string on each line character by character.

`output=output" "substr($0,i,2)} print output` -this is executed inside the above loop.  For each character of the string, the output variable is assigned to it's existing value, a space, then the two character substring from the current index - walking through each character and printing it and the following character.

Answer (score 1):

On GNU awk you can:

```
$ echo apple | gawk -F "" '{for(i=1;i<NF;)print $i$(++i)}'       # or use a file
ap
pp
pl
le
```

Works with mawk and Busybox awk also, all others will probably fail due to empty `FS` (`field separator FS is empty`)

Answer (score 1):

With a perl command line:

```
echo "apple" | perl -nE'say join " ",/(?<=\K.)./g'
```

Only one position is consumed by the pattern since one dot is inside a lookbehind, but the `\K` gives the position from which the match result is returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 'apple' |
  awk '{n=length($0)-1; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%s", substr($0,i,2), (i<n ? OFS : ORS)}'
ap pp pl le
```

Answer (score 0):

an expensive way

```
$ echo apple | fold -w1 | awk 'p{print p $0} {p=$0}' | xargs
ap pp pl le
```